# How to use Go on PowerPC

Tags: linux, go, powerpc

Is there a way to get Google Go to generate Linux/PowerPC executables?

**Update:** I guess this [announcement](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) helps a bit.

Comment: before diving into Go, I need to know if it generates PowerPC code so in short, no I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go compilers provided do not target Linux/ppc, but the GCC frontend, gccgo, may be able to.

Comment: I'm not sure if this guys's compile ever finished: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/15e70a7225f84638/f60b6f27f55ed8b9?pli=1

Comment: @mkb: That's OS X though, not Linux.

Comment: Right, but at least it's worth trying Linux-powerpc, not known to be a total waste of time.

Comment: Note that even if gccgo builds and is able to generate code, there will be more work to get system calls working. (Shouldn't be too hard, though, I don't think.) After that's out of the way, there's a small chance that everything else will work.

Answer (score 3):

Since Go version 1.5 ppc64 and ppc64le are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the go compiler package using the `golang` name available both on Debian and Ubuntu.

`➜  apt cache madison golang`

`golang | 2:1.6.1+1ubuntu2 | http://www.las.ic.unicamp.br/pub/ubuntu-ports yakkety/main ppc64el Packages
golang-defaults | 2:1.6.1+1ubuntu2 | http://www.las.ic.unicamp.br/pub/ubuntu-ports yakkety/main Sources`